# Loose socket plugs will not stay secure

Tags: home

I ordered snug plugs from Amazon to keep plugs in place but they don't work all the time.  Can you explain how to use the double-sided tape how and where on the socket do you apply it.

Comment: Please post a picture (or more) to understand the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent plugs from falling out of a wall socket?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20394/how-to-prevent-plugs-from-falling-out-of-a-wall-socket)

Comment: If the snug-plug doesn't work, try flipping it over so the right hand 'flap' goes into the left slot and vise-versa. Look closely and you'll see that one flap of the snug-plug is slightly wider than the other - it's easy to miss. Put the wide flap into the wide slot of the outlet receptacle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this isn't hacky enough, but I would replace the old loose receptacle with a newer, better quality one. You could also replace the plug/cord with a grounded 3 prong plug. I've never heard of the foam product, but I've avoided sticking things into power outlets ever since junior high school...

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the outlet! You paid more for them snug plugs, than it cost to buy a new outlet and cover.

Comment: Not true where I come from.  Plugs cost pence, a new socket is a few pounds.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Lifehacks.

The moderator Chenmunka offered the double-sided tape hack to hold an electrical plug securely in an electrical socket without explaining how to do it.

Here's how:

- Cut a small piece of the double-sided (foam) tape **that will fit between the prongs of the plug**.
- Put one side of the sticky tape on the plug.
- That done, peel off the back of the double-sided tape so that the exposed sticky back side will stick to the electrical socket wall plate.
- Push the plug far enough (all the way) into the socket so that the double-sided tape is between the plug and the socket so that the plug becomes stuck onto the plate.

I hope that's helpful.

Good luck.

Comment: New contributor Billy Goode noted that any use of tape to hold an electrical plug into a wall socket, must only be used when the appliance being plugged in isn't a large current drawing appliance such as a space heater or a power tool. The reason the plug falls out is because the socket itself is worn out. The surfaces could potentially produce a weak/or intermittent contact, increased electrical resistance, heat, and risk of electrical fire. So be careful, Better, call a professional, or at least consult a do-it-yourself electrical book.